# If I received XMR in a sub-address, will my balance correctly reflect this transaction in a wallet that does not support sub-addresses?

Tags: mymonero, sub-address

Lightweight wallets like MyMonero and Edge don't currently support sub-addresses. If I have the **same** wallet restored in the CLI or GUI and send XMR to a sub-address, is MyMonero or Edge consider it in the final balance?

Answer (score 2):

No. The wallet needs to support sub-addresses so the balance can be calculated correctly. Consider the scenario below:

1. You create a wallet in MyMonero and send 5 XMR.
2. You restore this wallet in the GUI.
3. You receive 2 XMR in a sub-address (acquired via GUI).

The MyMonero wallet will continue to show the balance of 5 XMR while the GUI will show 7 XMR.